# Multiply every row of a matrix with every row of another matrix

Tags: numpy, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

In numpy / PyTorch, I have two matrices, e.g. `X=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`, `Y=[[1,1],[2,2]]`. I would like to dot product every row of X with every row of Y, and have the results

```
[[3, 6],[7, 14], [11,22]]
```

How do I achieve this?, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

x= [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] 
y= [[1,1],[2,2]]

x = np.asarray(x) #convert list to numpy array 
y = np.asarray(y) #convert list to numpy array

product = np.dot(x, y.T)
```

`.T` transposes the matrix, which is neccessary in this case for the multiplication (because of the way dot products are [defined](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html)). `print(product)` will output:

```
[[ 3  6]
 [ 7 14]
 [11 22]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `einsum`

```
np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', X, Y)
```

```
array([[ 3,  6],
       [ 7, 14],
       [11, 22]])
```

Answer (score 1):

In `PyTorch`, you can achieve this using `torch.mm(a, b)` or `torch.matmul(a, b)`, as shown below:

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
y = np.array([[1,1],[2,2]])
x = torch.from_numpy(x)
y = torch.from_numpy(y)
# print(torch.matmul(x, torch.t(y)))
print(torch.mm(x, torch.t(y)))
```

output:

```
tensor([[ 3,  6],
        [ 7, 14],
        [11, 22]], dtype=torch.int32)
```